# Documentation about lmd5, lua module

Tags: module, lua

So, where do I find any documentation to use lmd5? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation. See the README file and code in the [provided archives](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lmd5). For more details, you should refer to the [OpenSSL library](http://www.openssl.org/) of which `lmd5` binds a few functions for use in Lua.

The author, [Luiz Henrique de Figueiredo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107090/lhf), is a StackOverflow user, and he would likely answer detailed questions concerning `lmd5` if you ask.